# Is "paper cutter" still used as a synonym of "paper knife"?

Tags: synonyms

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paper_cutter) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paper%20cutter) tell me that "papper cutter" is also a synonym of "paper knife". However, so far I've found only examples for this usage from the 19th century. Is "paper knife" prevalent these days? (Maybe the OED is clearer on this, but I don't have access to it right now.)

These are the three examples I had found:

> We were far from sanguine about the result of our adventure as we ran
>   our **paper-cutter** through the sheets: the event crowned the aphorism —
>   that such as expect little shall not be disappointed.

[Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=0oAEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22We%20were%20far%20from%20sanguine%20about%20the%20result%20of%20our%20adventure%20as%20we%20ran%20our%20paper-cutter%20through%20the%20sheets:%20the%20event%20crowned%20the%20aphorism%20%E2%80%94%20that%20such%20as%20expect%20little%20shall%20not%20be%20disappointed.%22&source=bl&ots=WwxiriqXIc&sig=-wATjBcQqsWmPD6jDP0E7Ff6jkk&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

> At first, indeed, as I skimmed the leaves, while dividing them with my
>   **paper-cutter** I thought that fourteen shillings for two duodecimo
>   volumes with handsome blanks at the end of each chapter, and about
>   three hundred lines of quoted poetry as mottoes was rather an
>   exorbitant sum.

[Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=zP5EAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=%22At%20first,%20indeed,%20as%20I%20skimmed%20the%20leaves,%20while%20dividing%20them%20with%20my%20paper-cutter%20I%20thought%20that%20fourteen%20shillings%20for%20two%20duodecimo%20volumes%20with%20handsome%20blanks%20at%20the%20end%20of%20each%20chapter,%20and%20about%20three%20hundred%20lines%20of%20quoted%20poetry%20as%20mottoes%20was%20rather%20an%20exorbitant%20sum.%22&source=bl&ots=PRLc9n18zI&sig=M9pf1cYqXIFMVxa5FPnOjnu1DJQ&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

> The beak, from a side view, has the appearance of being blunt at the
>   point, but is so compressed laterally as to be but little thicker than
>   an ivory **paper-cutter**, admirably adapted for being pushed in between
>   the shells of muscles, oysters, and other bivavles, the soft animals
>   of which are the principal food of this species.

[Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=1KY8AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=%22The%20beak,%20from%20a%20side%20view,%20has%20the%20appearance%20of%20being%20blunt%20at%20the%20point,%20but%20is%20so%20compressed%20laterally%20as%20to%20be%20but%20little%20thicker%20than%20an%20ivory%20paper-cutter,%20admirably%20adapted%20for%20being%20pushed%20in%20between%20the%20shells%20of%20muscles,%20oysters,%20and%20other%20bivavles,%20the%20soft%20animals%20of%20which%20are%20the%20principal%20food%20of%20this%20species.%22&source=bl&ots=TSE5qEQcSS&sig=vieHgB8V6QKaMoZyT5UDKN8Y5S4&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

Comment: When I was a kid in school we always had access [to one of these things](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/aplusautomation/vendorimages/c0f238aa-8b82-483f-affd-8bfc59ffafdc.jpg._CB300997949__SR300,300_.jpg), which are properly called "paper trimmers" but always referred to as "paper cutters" in the vernacular. You don't see them around much these days. But certainly you never see a "paper knife" in the 19th century sense, which were used to cut pages in books the binder had missed. They are completely obsolete. Today, a "paper knife" would mean "a knife made of paper".

Comment: I don't recall "paper knife" being used, at least as a common word, in AmE.  It's possible it's used in a paper-related trade, but "paper cutter" or "paper trimmer" is the common term related to slicing sheets or stacks of paper.  Wikipedia talks about paper knife as a synonym for letter opener but again, letter opener is the commonly used term there.

Comment: @fixer1234 According to [this blog post](https://regencyredingote.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/a-paper-knife-was-not-a-letter-opener/). *Paper knife* and *letter opener* are not synonymous. The latter evolved out of the former. A *paper knife* was used to cut pages of books apart that the bookbinder had accidentally left uncut.

Comment: @DanBron, I was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_knife.  I don't recall paper knife in common usage in the US in my lifetime.  Your blog reference looks British, so maybe it's a pond thing.  I'm not familiar enough with the term to have an opinion.

Comment: Are you talking about [guillotines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_cutter)?

Comment: Both the Oxford Dictionary and Merriam Webster list "paper cutter" as 1. a synonym of "paper knife"  and 2. the machine for cutting the edges of paper (a guillotine). My question is about the first defintion, whether this still applies or whether "paper cutter" in this sense is already archaic.

Comment: @Dan Bron (C1)  'Obsolete' as in 'no longer used as per design specs'? Almost. But 'obsolete' as in 'no longer fashionable'? They are collectables, often quite valuable. (C2) I'll check, but I'd say 'synonymous' applies to _paper knife_ and _letter opener_, as they were often used interchangeably. The blog post may well be arrogating the etymological fallacy..... Yep, [Freenet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/letter+opener) and [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/letter-opener).

Comment: Could you please provide links to your dictionary findings.

Comment: I had already edited my posts to include the dictionary findings. I have now also included the examples I had found.

Comment: @Turpidude, paper cutter is in common use.  Is your question about that or paper knife?  If paper knife, those are the references that might be helpful.

Comment: @fixer1234 It is about the "paper knife" in the sense of "letter opener". Wikipedia tells me that "paper knife" and "letter opener" are often used interchangeably in the vernacular, but that they actually have different functions. As a non-native speaker not living in an English-speaking country, this was not clear to me until I had seen the Wikipedia article.

Comment: So "paper cutter" was/is actually a synonym for the paper knives that "were used during the Regency period for cutting pages of books when book presses were new and not able to efficiently separate each page for reading." and not for "letter opener"?

Comment: @Turpidude, there are at least three kinds of uses.  In bookbinding, there is or was a tool for separating pages.  It looks like that was called a paper knife, at least at some point.  Bookbinding is a specialty trade, so the terms used aren't necessarily the same as general usage.  The bookbinding process and tools could also have changed over time.  For example, at some time in the past, they may have used a knife to separate individual pages.  Later, they might have gone to a heavy-duty cutter to trim entire books, or multiple books, at once.  (cont'd)

Comment: So it may not be that the name of the tool changed, the terms may refer to different tools used to achieve a similar end result.  Aside from bookbinding, there are tools for dividing sheets or trimming stacks of paper (e.g., guillotine style or rolling blades).  Those are commonly called paper cutters or paper trimmers.  Then there are letter openers, and those apparently are or were also referred to as paper knives, at least in some places.  And those might be similar to what was used in bookbinding.  So it looks like there are a number of dimensions to the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's not so much a "side of the pond" issue as it is a "side of the twentieth century" issue. It used to be common for books to arrive from the bookseller "uncut", meaning the pages were folded closed for binding and thus unreadable; a reader needed to literally cut the pages open with a tool similar to a letter opener. By the end of the nineteenth century booksellers were mostly "pre-cutting" books, though the process could still easily miss pages. Advances in technology and changes in bookbinding make that almost unheard-of today, and so most of us will never need a "paper knife".

Comment: @1006a, I learned something new.  So far, it looks like you may be the only reader who has any familiarity with this.  Consider posting an answer

Comment: OED: _A slim knife used for slitting paper along a fold, such as when opening a letter or separating uncut leaves in a book._  Examples confirming comments:
1789   Catal. Plate, China, & Other Effects B. Bartlett 3  Two spying-glasses, an opera-glass, a paper-knife, etc.
1947   Z. Grey Valley of Wild Horses ii. 27 Dick had turned—with the teacher's long paper knife in his hand and baleful hate in his prominent eyes.
1997   J. Updike Toward End of Time 61   Boxes of turn-of-the-century first editions..that he slit, as he read, with a little ivory paper knife in his signet-ringed right hand.

Comment: @1006a   I have flagged this post to ask the mods to delete all these comments, which dissuade users from actually posting answers. Please post an answer, just C/P your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I may be old-fashioned, but I (British) would call a letter-opener a paper knife. And I would call Dan Bron's 'one of these things' a guillotine.